# transform dataframe according to index and labels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
ID | TEXT | LABEL|

5  | blab | 0 
5  | blub | 0 
5  | gray | 0 
4  | rose | 1 
4  | work | 1 
4  | app  | 1 
3  | car  | 0 
3  | ink  | 0
1  | pink | 0
```

And I'm struggling to transform it to look like this:

```
ID | TEXT | TEXT| TEXT | LABEL|
5  | blab | blub| gray | 0 
4  | rose | work| app  | 1
3  | car  |     |      | 0 
1  | pink |     |      | 0
```

I have tried `df.T` and `df.pivot()` for now but I can't seem to get it right - any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to pivoting with two columns. Basically, you need to enumerate the rows within the groups before pivot:

```
# maybe groupby on `ID` is enough, depending on your data
(df.assign(col=df.groupby(['ID','LABEL']).cumcount())
   .pivot_table(index=['ID','LABEL'], columns='col', 
                values='TEXT', aggfunc='first')
   .add_prefix('TEXT_')
   .reset_index() 
)
```

Or similarly with `set_index().unstack()`:

```
(df.set_index(['ID','LABEL', df.groupby(['ID']).cumcount()])
   ['TEXT'].unstack()
   .add_prefix('TEXT_')
   .reset_index() 
)
```

Output:

```
col  ID  LABEL TEXT_0 TEXT_1 TEXT_2
0     1      0   pink    NaN    NaN
1     3      0    car    ink    NaN
2     4      1   rose   work    app
3     5      0   blab   blub   gray
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
out = df.groupby(['ID','LABEL']).TEXT.agg(list).apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
Out[491]: 
   ID  LABEL     0     1     2
0   1      0  pink   NaN   NaN
1   3      0   car   ink   NaN
2   4      1  rose  work   app
3   5      0  blab  blub  gray
```