# Pandas Pivot Table Based on Specific Column Value

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I need to pivot my data in a df like shown below based on a specific date in the YYMMDD and HHMM column "20180101 100". This specific date represents a new category of data with equal amounts of rows. I plan on replacing the repeating column names in the output with unique names. Suppose my data looks like this below.

```
        YYMMDD  HHMM  BestGuess(kWh)
0     20180101  100    20
1     20180101  200    70
0     20201231  2100   50
1     20201231  2200   90
2     20201231  2300   70
3     20210101  000    40    
4     20180101  100    5
5     20180101  200    7
6     20201231  2100   2
7     20201231  2200   3
8     20201231  2300   1
9     20210101  000    4
```

I need the new df (dfpivot) to look like this:

```
        YYMMDD  HHMM  BestGuess(kWh)  BestGuess(kWh)
0     20180101  100    20               5
1     20180101  200    70               7
2     20201231  2100   50               2
3     20201231  2200   90               3
4     20201231  2300   70               1
5     20210101  000    40               4
```

Comment: Almost identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802411/transform-dataframe-according-to-index-and-labels/66802489#66802489).

Answer (score 0):

Does this suffice?

```
cols = ['YYMMDD', 'HHMM']
df.set_index([*cols, df.groupby(cols).cumcount()]).unstack()

              BestGuess(kWh)   
                           0  1
YYMMDD   HHMM                  
20180101 100              20  5
         200              70  7
20201231 2100             50  2
         2200             90  3
         2300             70  1
20210101 0                40  4
```

More fully baked

```
cols = ['YYMMDD', 'HHMM']
temp = df.set_index([*cols, df.groupby(cols).cumcount()]).unstack()
temp.columns = [f'{l0} {l1}' for l0, l1 in temp.columns]
temp.reset_index()

     YYMMDD  HHMM  BestGuess(kWh) 0  BestGuess(kWh) 1
0  20180101   100                20                 5
1  20180101   200                70                 7
2  20201231  2100                50                 2
3  20201231  2200                90                 3
4  20201231  2300                70                 1
5  20210101     0                40                 4
```